# Ionic 2 app android version 4.4.2

Tags: android, ionic2

When I run this :

```
$ cordova build --release android
```

I get my .apk file, but it is for android 6,my phone is on android 4.4.2, so when I run the .apk file on my device but it give me an error :

```
Application not installed
```

Anyone know how to solve it? Maybe a flag for android version..Sorry I'm newer

Comment: did you try `ionic build android --release --prod` or `ionic run android`?

Comment: @suraj again you!Thnak you..anyway no,I'm trying now